# Nightmare.js can't find css tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am currently developing a program to automate a task on a certain website (the simplified code is below).
 I login nicely and then wait for the page to load, but the wait function never ends. I tried using wait(200), but then the evaluate function returns an empty array. I am 100% sure there are p.reference elements in the website. 
Does anyone know what is happening?

```js
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare

  .goto('https://somewebsite.com')
  
  .insert('input#username', 'abc@abc.com')
  .insert('input#password', 'abc') 
  .click('button#Login')
  .wait('p.reference')
  .evaluate(selector=>{
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  },'p.reference'
  )
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
})
```

Comment: yes. I am editing it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the password lookup.
Since you're looking for a field with the class **password** so you need to change into

```
  .insert('input#password', 'abc')
```

OR

```
  .insert('input.password', 'abc')
```

But I would bet is the first one, according to the other field.

Comment: The password is fine, it is only a typo from posting here. The login works fine and I am redirected to the next page